# How to create links which pass arguments to a page?

Tags: navigation

I am making a website which displays table from a database. For every row of the table I want to provide a link(or button) which will be placed in the last column and will redirect to a page displaying records from another table associated with that row. Is there a way to create such link which would pass an argument (row id) to another page so it could display apropriate records?
Thanks

Comment: You can use l() function https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7

Comment: @AkashJain if you would elaborate a bit, it might be a good answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function, Like

Suppose You are showing some data in table format as you mention in your question and using some query you get some data from databse in $result variable,

> $header = array(t('Approved By'), t('Role'), t('Points'), t('View
> More'));
>
> foreach ($result as $row) {
>
> $rows[] = array($row['user_name'], $row['user_role'], $row['date'], l(t('View'), 'node/' . $row['row_id']));
>
> }
>
> return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

Now above code create a page showing table

```
Approved By    Role                    Points    View More
Eve            content writer          94        View    -> url: my-page/1

John           content manager         80        View    -> url: my-page/2

Adam           manager                 67        View    -> url: my-page/3
  
Jill           admin                   50        View    -> url: my-page/4
```

> function my_module_menu() {
>     $item['my-page/%'] = array(
>         'title' => 'my page',
>         'page_callback' => array()
>         'page callback' => 'my_page_callback',
>         'page arguments' => array(1),
>         'access arguments' => array('access content overview')
>     );
>
> return $item; }
>
> function my_page_callback($row_id) {
>     // Get some data from database using $row_id
>     // show in table
> }

Comment: That looks allright but my problem lies somewhere else. I need to pass the id of a row to a page function, which would fetch a set of rows from a database (not nodes) and display the table after clicking the link. I hope I made it clear this time.

Comment: @Gregson: I have edited the answer, Hope this will solve your problem, let me know if you any issue.

Comment: This works, thank you very much. Now it would be even better if I could do the same thing without displaying the data in the url address. If I won't find out how to do that, I will stick to this solution.

Comment: It doesn't have to be based on url link, maybe I could use a set of form submit buttons, but I am not sure that it is possible in this situation or how to implement that kind of solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Change url my-page/{row-id} to my-page and using javascript you can do that, on click just save row id in cookie, and then on page callback you will get value from cookie. But i am not recommend you to do in this way.